# Trying to see if object key exists keep getting undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data response that responds with different objects in an array.

I have tried a variety of different methods to determine if the key 'name' exists including:

```
const hasName = array.forEach(item => "name" in item )

const hasName = array.forEach(item => Object.keys(item).includes('name') )

const hasName = array[0].hasOwnProperty("name") ? true : null

const hasName = array => array.some(x => x.some(({ name }) => name));

// lodash 'has' method
const hasName = has(array, 'name')
```

Array1 returns objects like:

```
[
  {
   name: 'cool name'
  }
]
```

Array2 returns objects like:

```
[
  {
   group: 'cool group'
  }
]
```

All of the methods I tried have either returned `undefined` or nothing at all and I'm completely at a loss for why. I have scoured Stack Overflow and the internet trying to get a better direction or an answer but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from some of your calls on the array. `forEach` for example runs a callback, and always returns `undefined` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value). Your code just isn't working because you're using the functions incorrectly.

The code below filters your array to get the elements with a name property, then counts them to see whether one or more exists, which results in a `true` or `false` being stored in the `hasName` variable.

```js
let myArr = [
  {
   name: 'cool name'
  }
]

const hasName = 
  myArr
    .filter(a => a.hasOwnProperty("name")) // filter for elements in the array which have a name property
    .length // get the number of filtered elements
    > 0 // check whether the number of elements in array with name prop is more than 0


console.log(hasName)
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are sure that the "response" is fully received before the check, THEN**
Your latest variant of the check can be implemented as follows:

```js
array.some(obj => (obj.name !== undefined)); // fast, but not define .name if it is "undefined"
array.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("name")); // slower, but will define .name with any value
```

Your solutions are generally correct, but it looks like you're a little confused,

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) always returns "undefined":

```js
array.forEach(obj => {
    console.log("name" in obj); // true for 1st array
    console.log("group" in obj); // true for 2nd array
}); // return "undefined"
```

`array[0].hasOwnProperty()` works fine, and can't return "undefined" at all.

```js
console.log(
    array[0].hasOwnProperty("name") ? true : null; // return ("true" for the 1st array) AND ("null" for the 2nd)
);
```

When you used the Lodash, maybe you forgot to point to the object index?

```js
_.has(array[0], 'name'); // return ("true" for the 1st array) AND ("false" for the 2nd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].hasOwnProperty('name')) {
        console.log(array[i].name); //do something here.
        break;
    }
}
```